# Multiple loops following string and subsets

Tags: r

I'm currently stuck with my data frame and i would like to know how to do "subsets of subsets of subsets"
Here is a part of my data frame:

```
    YEAR    RN      DATE    NAME            SITE           LONG SP                         SUMNB            NB100
1   2011    RNN027  15056   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol 02  310 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758) 1   0.3225806
2   2011    RNN027  15075   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol 02  310 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758) 1   0.3225806
3   2003    RNN027  12166   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol 03  330 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758) 2   0.6060606
4   2006    RNN027  13252   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol 03  330 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758) 2   0.6060606
5   2006    RNN027  13257   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol 03  330 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758) 2   0.6060606
6   2005    RNN027  12895   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol 01  540 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758) 2   0.3703704
```

My point is to compute a abundance factor for each species. To do that, i have to isolate every count date for every species, every year, and every site.

My first idea was to do multiple loops and subseting every step by the previous criteria:

DF --> Loop SITE ; subset of each SITE -->loop YEAR; subset of each YEAR -->loop SP; subset of each SPECIES-->  dates of observations

The point of isolating these dates require further modifications (adding rows), but i need to be capable of rewriting the modified subsets afterwards and reconstruct a new dataframe.

I built my loops command:

```
LOOPSITE<-sort(unique(DF$SITE))
for(i in LOOPSITE){
  print(i)
  LOOPSITESUB<-subset(DF,grepl(i,SITE))
  LOOPYEAR<-sort(unique(LOOPSITESUB$YEAR))
  print(LOOPYEAR)

  for(j in LOOPYEAR){
    print(j)
    LOOPYEARSUB<-subset(LOOPSITESUB,grepl(j,YEAR))
    LOOPSP<-sort(unique(LOOPYEARSUB$SP))
    print(length(LOOPSP))
       for(k in LOOPSP){
         print(k)
         LOOPSPSUB<-subset(LOOPYEARSUB,grepl(k,SP))
         print(sum(LOOPYEARSUB$SUMNB))
         print(head(LOOPSPSUB))
    }      
  }
}
```

I am able to follow that my script is working with all these "print" commands, and it is working until i reach the species subseting. For an unknown reason, the last subsetting dont concern each species, but only some of them. Here is a part of the output for the last SITE and the last YEAR:

```
"RNN027-Estagnol 01"
...(I skipped all the sites)
"RNN027-Estagnol 06"
"2003"
...(I skipped all the years)
"2011"
[1] 22
[1] "Aricia agestis D., 1775"
[1] 107
   YEAR     RN       DATE      NOM               SITE LONG                      SP SUMNB     NB100
66 2011 RNN027 2011-04-21 ESTAGNOL RNN027-Estagnol 06  260 Aricia agestis D., 1775         1 0.3846154
67 2011 RNN027 2011-05-22 ESTAGNOL RNN027-Estagnol 06  260 Aricia agestis D., 1775     1 0.3846154
68 2011 RNN027 2011-08-05 ESTAGNOL RNN027-Estagnol 06  260 Aricia agestis D., 1775     2 0.7692308
[1] "Brintesia circe (Fabricius, 1775)"
[1] 107
[1] YEAR  RN    DATE  NOM   SITE  LONG  SP    SUMNB NB100
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
[1] "Carcharodus alceae (Esper, 1780)"
[1] 107
[1] YEAR  RN    DATE  NOM   SITE  LONG  SP    SUMNB NB100
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

It is working for "Aricia agestis D., 1775" but not for "Brintesia circe (Fabricius, 1775)".
I verified on my dataframe, that second species have been observed at this time and place,and have the same format than the previous one...it should be working.

How many loops can i stack like this ? Is there another way to do that? (it would be convenient and faster). I'm aware of the "split" function, who basically dismont every group, but as i cant exploit every"chunk", it dont fit to my task. I am maybe wrong.

At the last step (after modifing all the subsets), i should be able to write each subset in a new dataframe to reconstruct a modified version of my input.

I'm am maybe on the wrongest way i possibly can go!
I can provide further explanations if needed!

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

I'll try to explain what i want to do.
In order to calculate my abundance index, i need to add "blank" rows before and after each temporal "session" of observation. Basically, i try to obtain a subset for every combination of 3 differents factors (SITE, YEAR and SP).

Here is an example of the type of output i would like to obtain.
 For every SITE X/YEAR Y/SP Z possible combination:

```
 YEAR    RN      DATE    NAME            SITE           LONG SP  SUMNB NB100
----ADD A NEW ROW----DATE MINUS 7 DAYS-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Y    RNN027  15056   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol X  310 SP Z  1   0.3225806
2   Y    RNN027  15075   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol X  310 SP Z  1   0.3225806
3   Y    RNN027  12166   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol X  330 SP Z  2   0.6060606
4   Y    RNN027  13252   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol X  330 SP Z  2   0.6060606
5   Y    RNN027  13257   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol X  330 SP Z  2   0.6060606
6   Y    RNN027  12895   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol X  540 SP Z  2   0.3703704
----ADD A NEW ROW----DATE PLUS 7 DAYS-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then i rewrite and compile every modified subset in a new DF.

EDIT 2:
The use of "split(DF, list(DF$SITE, DF$YEAR, DF$SP))" crashed my computer, unless I dropped the unused values. I got exactly what I want, but how can I access and modify every subset ?

Comment: Could you please add the output of `dput(head(DF))` to your question?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it seems that you want to 'calculate something per group' - abundance per species, site and year. If so, you might look have a look [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) and [**here**](http://lamages.blogspot.se/2012/01/say-it-in-r-with-by-apply-and-friends.html) for some ideas. And heaps of posts on this topic on SO. Cheers.

Comment: For now, i dont want to calculate anything. In order to calculate my index without underestimating anything, I need to add a row before and after each subset. These rows will have a date set on 7 days before the first date and after the last date of observation. If i understand what is said in your first link (SO), i could apply that function with "tapply" but only for one factor right ?

Comment: To be honest I'm not clear with what you want, but is this of any use: `split(DF, list(DF$SITE, DF$YEAR, DF$SP), sep = " _ ")` and `lapply(split(DF, list(DF$SITE, DF$YEAR, DF$SP), sep = " _ "), function(x) x$DATE)`? Maybe you could add a desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(SUMNB ~ SITE + YEAR + SP, DF, sum)

#                 SITE YEAR                                      SP SUMNB
# 1 RNN027-Estagnol 03 2003 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     2
# 2 RNN027-Estagnol 01 2005 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     2
# 3 RNN027-Estagnol 03 2006 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     4
# 4 RNN027-Estagnol 02 2011 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     2
```

The command calculates the sum of all values in `SUMNB` for each combination of `SITE`, `YEAR` and `SP`.

---

*Edit*

Does the following code produce what your're looking for?

```
do.call(rbind, by(DF, DF[c("SITE", "YEAR", "SP")], FUN = function(x) {
  tmp <- x[c(1, seq(nrow(x)), nrow(x)), ]
  tmp$DATE[1] < tmp$DATE[1] - 7
  tmp$DATE[nrow(tmp)] <- tmp$DATE[nrow(tmp)] + 7
  return(tmp)
}))
```

Comment: In order to build my input DF, i already did aggregate. As explained in the other answer's comments, i need to add rows before and after each "chunk". Aggregate dont allow me to do that.

Comment: @user2542995 Which values do you want in the other columns of the additional rows?

Comment: Yes it is working! I was able to set the values of SUMNB and NB100 to zero as i wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edits, I believe this could be useful:

```
set.seed(11)
DF <- data.frame(YEAR = sample(c(2001, 2003), 5, T),     #random data
                 SITE = sample(c("a", "b"), 5, T),
                 SP = sample(c("sp1", "sp2"), 5, T),
                 DATE = sample(12345:15678, 5))

res <- lapply(split(DF, list(DF$SITE, DF$YEAR, DF$SP)), 
                function(x) 
                {
                 if(nrow(x) > 0)
                  {
                   row1 <- x[1,]
                   names(row1) <- colnames(x)
                   row1["DATE"] <- x$DATE[1] - 7

                   rown <- x[nrow(x),]
                   names(rown) <- colnames(x)
                   rown["DATE"] <- x$DATE[nrow(x)] + 7

                   rbind(row1, x, rown)
                  } 
                })
DF2 <- do.call(rbind, res)
rownames(DF2) = seq_len(nrow(DF2))

DF
#  YEAR SITE  SP  DATE
#1 2001    b sp1 14257
#2 2001    a sp1 13950
#3 2003    a sp2 13446
#4 2001    b sp2 12870
#5 2001    a sp2 13943
DF2
#   YEAR SITE  SP  DATE
#1  2001    a sp1 13943
#2  2001    a sp1 13950
#3  2001    a sp1 13957
#4  2001    b sp1 14250
#5  2001    b sp1 14257
#6  2001    b sp1 14264
#7  2001    a sp2 13936
#8  2001    a sp2 13943
#9  2001    a sp2 13950
#10 2001    b sp2 12863
#11 2001    b sp2 12870
#12 2001    b sp2 12877
#13 2003    a sp2 13439
#14 2003    a sp2 13446
#15 2003    a sp2 13453
```

Comment: My DF is too heavy and this command takes too much time on my computer. But still, it is working! Thanks!